# min() function not working correctly, gives wrong output

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a problem which is based on the traveling salesman problem and for some reason the `min()` function does not give me the correct number when comparing with another floating-point number

I have tried putting float() around the floats I am comparing but that just gave me the same output

```
prn = [0]
for _ in range(1, N):
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        mn = 100
        mni = 0
        chk = sqrt((lst[i][1][0] - last[0])**2 + (lst[i][1][1] - last[1])**2)
        if int(chk) < int(mn):
            mn = chk
            mni = lst[i][0]
            delete = i
            last = lst[delete][1]
    lst.pop(delete)
    prn.append(mni)
    print(mn)
```

when running the input which you can find here: https://iceland.kattis.com/problems/iceland.landsreisa/file/statement/attachments/iceland.txt
the `prn` list is `[0, 453, 452, ..., 2, 1]` instead of `[0, 4, 13, ..., xn-1, xn]` so the `min()` function makes `mn` equal to the last thing it was fed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't see where in your code you are calling the min() function? Or is the cod example you posted an implementation of a min function? If so, could you try and be a bit clearer about what you are trying to do and what the expected output is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    mn = 100
    mni = 0
    chk = sqrt((lst[i][1][0] - last[0])**2 + (lst[i][1][1] - last[1])**2)
    if int(chk) < int(mn):
        mn = chk
        mni = lst[i][0]
```

Notice how you always set mn and mni to 100 and 0 with each iteration, so you're always comparing chk to 100. So, when you append mni it will be either the value of lst[i][0] at the last iteration, or 0.

I'm assuming this is your implementation of min() and that mni means min, and you defined mn and mni elsewhere, because they aren't in scope.